# Firebase SDK with PHP - Fatal Error: The requested client requires the gRPC extension

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, grpc

I'm running PHP 7.4.3 and NGINX 1.18.0 on Ubuntu 20.04

I followed the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc to install gRPC.

When I run `php -m`, "grpc" is in the list of PHP Modules.

Ultimately, my site resolves in a 500 error with the following entry in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\GoogleException: The requested client requires the gRPC extension. Please see https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc for installation instructions. in /vendor/google/cloud-core/src/ClientTrait.php:75

As far as I can tell, gRPC is installed. I know of no other ways to validate its presence.

Answer (score 3):

Running php from the cmdline usually uses a different php.ini file to what the webserver uses.

To verify the presence of a module, you would need to create a page on the website to verify the module exists

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

As a side note, if it is a public website, don't call the file phpinfo.php and be sure to remove it after you have checked the output, as it is a security risk to expose that information about your server.

Comment: This was the issue! As per the gRPC installation docs, I used `php --ini` to get the path to my php.ini file (/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini). Then I added `extension=grpc.so` to that file. I should have noticed the "cli" in the path and put two and two together.

After running `phpinfo()` from the browser, I found that the proper php.ini was located at `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini`.

I loaded the extension via that ini file, restarted PHP-FPM (sudo service php7.4-fpm restart) and fixed the issue.

Thanks for your help!